# Eclipse Project Source Menu only showing "Format"

Tags: java, eclipse

**Noob alert**: when I right-click on my eclipse project, the "Source" menu only shows "Format". On my co-workers' mahcines, the Source menu has about two dozen options. Specifically, I want to run Source-->Clean Up. How can I do this if it isn't showing in the menu?

Comment: What perspective are you in, and what perspective is your coworker in? The features available under Source (and other menus) change depending on the perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, sorry guys. In typical noob fashion, I'm also answering my own question. I figured out that I was right-clicking on my project in `Navigator` instead of `Package Explorer`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to compare the project facets of your workspace and your friends.

right click on your project -> choose properties -> project facets

Comment: I have no "Project Facets" under properties.

Comment: did you follow the path as above? it should be there.